# Generics & Inheritance: What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-3.5, casting, polymorphism

There are the following 4 objects declared:

```
abstract class AConfigAction {}

abstract class APlugin<ConfigActionType> where ConfigActionType :AConfigAction {}

class AppExecuteConfigAction : AConfigAction {}

class AppExecutePlugin : APlugin<AppExecuteConfigAction>{}
```

- All classes are public. Bodies have been removed for simplicity.

Why this fails to be converted?

```
_plugins = new List<APlugin<AConfigAction>>();
_plugins.Add(new AppExecutePlugin());  <--- Error
```

> cannot convert from 'AppExecutePlugin' to 'APlugin'

---

Full error message:

> Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List>.Add(EnvironmentSwitcher.Model.ConfigAction.APlugin)' has some invalid arguments R:\projects\EnvironmentSwitcher\EnvironmentSwitcher\View\ConfigurationActionManagerForm.cs  35
>
> Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'EnvironmentSwitcher.Model.ConfigAction.AppExecute.AppExecutePlugin' to 'EnvironmentSwitcher.Model.ConfigAction.APlugin'  R:\projects\EnvironmentSwitcher\EnvironmentSwitcher\View\ConfigurationActionManagerForm.cs  35

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's make that a bit easier to understand:

```
abstract class Animal {} // was AConfigAction
abstract class Cage<T> where T : Animal {} // was APlugIn
class Tiger : Animal {} // was AppExecuteConfigAction
class TigerCage : Cage<Tiger>{} // was AppExecutePlugin

var cages = new List<Cage<Animal>>();    
cages.Add(new TigerCage()); // Why is this an error?
```

Suppose that were legal. What stops this?

```
class Shark : Animal {} // some other config action
...
var cages = new List<Cage<Animal>>();    
cages.Add(new TigerCage()); 
Cage<Animal> firstCage = cages[0]; 
firstCage.InsertIntoCage(new Shark());
```

firstCage is of type `Cage<Animal>` which implies that it can hold any kind of animal. But in fact we know that it is a tigers-only cage. You just put a shark into a tiger cage, which seems uncomfortable for both the shark and the tiger.

Obviously that cannot be allowed. What prevents it? The only thing that prevents it is that it is illegal to put a tiger cage into a collection of animal cages in the first place.  A tiger cage is *not* a kind of animal cage because there are things you can do with an animal cage that you *cannot* do with a tiger cage, namely, put a shark into it. A basic principle of object-oriented design is that subtypes can do everything their supertypes can do; a tiger cage cannot do everything an animal cage can do, so it is not a subtype.

The more highfalutin way to say this is that *generic types cannot be made to be covariant in their type arguments because doing so would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle*. In C# 4, certain interfaces and delegates *are* covariant in their type arguments. For example, it is legal in C# 4 to put an `IEnumerable<Tiger>` into a  `List<IEnumerable<Animal>>>` because there's no way that this can be made unsafe. We can uphold the substitution principle while allowing covariance because `IEnumerable<T>` is an "out-only" interface. You only ever take tigers out; there's no way to put sharks in.

Comment: Good idea with the cage analogy... :)

Comment: If `Cage<T>` is an abstract class, and no `class AnimalCage : Cage<Animal>{}` exists, how can you call `InsertIntoCage` on `firstCage`?

Comment: Another question is what *can* you put into a `List<Cage<Animal>>`?

Comment: Your the best crafts man to explain complex confusing stuffs with a simple example. I still rem one of ur example used 2 explain 1 of my doubts i.e Rain has come, so road is wet. But does not mean that road gets wet only because of rain :)

Comment: @comecme: Re: your first question: I don't understand the question. You are asking how you can call a method on an abstract class?  By calling it. What's the problem?

Comment: @comecme: Re: your second question: You can put an instance of any type derived from `Cage<Animal>` into such a list. `TigerCage` is not derived from `Cage<Animal>` -- it is derived from `Cage<Tiger>` which is a different type entirely.

Comment: Re my 1st question. You are right. For some reason I thought an abstract class wouldn't contain any implemented methods. But... if `Cage<T>` implements `InsertIntoCage(T animal)` then why would it be wrong to put a Shark into it? I'd think that having an `InsertIntoCage` implementation would mean the class is able to put any kind of animal into the cage.

Comment: @comecme: `Cage<T>.Insert(T t)` can put a *T* into the cage for whatever T is. If you wanted to represent "I can insert any animal" then what do you need T for? You'd just say `Cage.Insert(Animal animal)`. The whole point of generics is that they substitute the type argument in for T.

Answer (score 4):

[Generics covariance and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) is supported in C# 4.0. It works with interfaces though and not abstract classes:

```
abstract class AConfigAction { }

interface APlugin<out ConfigActionType> where ConfigActionType : AConfigAction { }

class AppExecuteConfigAction : AConfigAction { }

class AppExecutePlugin : APlugin<AppExecuteConfigAction> { }

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var _plugins = new List<APlugin<AConfigAction>>();
        _plugins.Add(new AppExecutePlugin());
    }
}
```

In C# 3.5 this is not supported.

Comment: @odyodyodys, it defines the `ConfigActionType` generic argument as covariant meaning that members inside this interface can only return it but not take as argument.

Comment: I suppose this is a .Net 4 feature (as I can understand from yours and Eric's answer).

Comment: @odyodyodys, yes, it is a .NET 4.0 feature.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Interestingly, the generic variance feature was added to the CLR type system in .NET 2.0 -- it has been there as long as generics have been available. But no types in the base class libraries were marked as covariant or contravariant and no mainstream language took advantage of the feature until v4.0, oddly enough. But you can use ILASM to build covariant interfaces in CLR v2 if you really want to.

Comment: @EricLippert, thanks for pointing this out. You are absolutely right. I have replaced `.NET 4.0` with `C# 4.0` in my answer to take your remark into account.